# What Happens to the Daemon Threads once JVM exists?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

Most documents say "JVM exits when there are no non-daemon threads", so then what happens to the Daemon Threads? How are the exceptions handled , their objects handled ... ?

Can anyone explain the post-JVM_Exit life of Daemon threads ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the daemon threads are halted abruptly.  As for "their objects," objects are just memory locations.  At a JVM exit all memory is simply returned to the OS, no further actions are taken.  (There's a JVM exit hook, but this is known to be fraught and it's not recommended to use it.)

Comment: Thanks ,  can you provide me some pointer to look into :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain the post-JVM_Exit life of Daemon threads ?

There isn't any. The process has exited; all its threads are gone; all its memory is released to the operating system; all its semaphores and locks are released; all its open files and sockets are closed, not necessarily cleanly.